# Java: String reference getting unexpected output

Tags: java, string

My code is :

```
String str = "Hello";
String str1;
str1 = str;
str1 = str1 + " World";
System.out.println(str1);
System.out.println(str);
```

The output I get is :

```
Hello World
Hello
```

The output I was expecting is `Hello World` for both the cases because according to my understanding after `str1 = str` both objects are referencing to same location so if I change the content of one object other should also get affected.

So, is `str1 = str1 + " World";` creating a new string object at different memory loction.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings are immutable. When you do `str1 = str1 + " World";`, you're creating a totally new String and updating `str1`'s reference to it. You're never re-asigning `str` so this IS the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The point is that the `+` operator creates a new String object, effectively concatenating the operands.  It does not modify the object `str`.

You might want to read http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.at/2010/10/why-string-is-immutable-in-java.html, which explains the concept of immutable strings quite nicely.

The class `StringBuffer` might also be worth noting, which is optimized for long, cascaded concatenations.

Comment: Interesting blog post. Thanks for it.

Comment: It was really the first google hit for `java string immutable` ;)

Answer (score 2):

In Java String is immutable.

`str1 = str1 + " World";` It will create a new instance and assign to str1.

Answer (score 2):

java.lang.String is immutable

```
str1 = str1 + " World";
```

This code will make str1 reference to a new created String object `"Hello World"`, and str still reference to the `"Hello"` object.

Answer (score 2):

Reference to primitive datetypes creates always a new Object

Answer (score 1):

No, this is the right out put as in the code you had init the string

```
String str = "Hello";
 String str1;
```

Then you say

```
str1 = str;
```

it means `str1` contains "Hello"

```
str1 = str1 + " World";
```

The above line will print "Hello World" because `str1` having "Hello" and   " World" is given there as a new string

and when you print `str` it is containing the word "Hello"

```
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is so special about String in here, It's the common behavior for all. It's about the assignment operator (in line number 4 you assigning it again). Your code is similar to below.

```
Person p1 = new Person("Stack");
Person p2;
p2 = p1;
p1 = new Person("OverFlow");
```

What would this Print? Would both print "Overflow"?

From your words.

> The output I was expecting is Hello World for both the cases because
>   according to my understanding after **str1 = str both objects are
>   referencing to same location** so if I change the content of one object
>   other should also get affected.

```
Line 3: str1 = str;
```

As per Line number 3 you are correct.

```
Line 4: str1 = str1 + " World";
```

But in line number 4 you are not changing the content, you are reassigning str1 to a different object.

Here str, str1 and p1 are Object references. Not real objects. You would get same content if you are changing the object. Like

p1 = p1.setName("Overflow");